# Docker Big Log Rollout Update settings problem

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a problem about docker log setting and wonder if anyone here could help me.
my docker generates a lot of logs, so I set up a rolling update for it, the settings are as follows:

```
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-level": "warn",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-file": "10",
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
```

In this way, its log collection will be as follows:
[image]

and when I use `kubectl logs`, it only read the latest file, which means that at some time, when the log file is just 100M, the latest file will be empty. I wonder if I have a way to read the latest 100M log every time, rather than the latest file. Or how to configure it? Docker can put the latest 100m log in the latest file.

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2):

According to the K8S Documentation what you describe is standard behavior and can't be modified:

[Logging at the node level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)

> Note: Currently, if some external system has performed the rotation, only the contents of the latest log file will be available through kubectl logs. E.g. if there’s a 10MB file, logrotate performs the rotation and there are two files, one 10MB in size and one empty, kubectl logs will return an empty response.

I recommend introducing log aggregation to your cluster with a daemon set, e.g. [Fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd) with [ElasticSearch and Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html).

Comment: Thank you. But I'm thinking about whether the daemonset mode is a good way. My log files will be relatively large, if it will lead to a lot of resources needed for the deamonset pod? Then in fact, I hope to get the standard output log through the **client-go** . Could I do this in the deamonset mode?

Comment: All your standard out logs are written to disk by Docker to /var/lib/containers Timber.io reaps them from there and forwards them to Timer HQ, so yes, the Daemoset approach works well with Stdout.

Comment: @edselwang Very good point. Fluentd with ElasticSearch & Kibana is the way to go.